# Iterate a value when similar value within a column in R

Tags: r

[ISIN Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFWtW.png)

Hello everyone,

I have a question regarding a data frame of ISIN numbers. I want unique values so I would like to iterate the ISIN whenever the ISIN is similar to the one in the previous row. For instance, the 5 first row should look like this: "US0003602069", "US0003602069.1", "US0003602069.2", "US0003602069.3", "US0003602069.4", "US0003602069.5".

Any ideas on how to do this on R?

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO. The community will be more helpful If you can describe in details what you are trying to do and what is the exact problem you are facing. This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `make.names()`

```
x <- rep("US0003602069", 5)
make.names(x, unique = T)

# [1] "US0003602069"   "US0003602069.1" "US0003602069.2" "US0003602069.3" "US0003602069.4"
```